# How do I switch user in CME using Google Chrome browser?

Tags: web8.5

How do I switch between two users in CME using Google Chrome browser? Currently, my testing team is using two user logins for testing purpose, and they want to switch between these two users in Google Chrome.

Does the CME support switching between users in Chrome browser?

Any suggestion and recommendations are welcome.

Comment: The only reliable way I've achieved this is by using Incognito. Maybe this helps? http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Logout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no logout functionality in Tridion. That being said, the only way you can switch user is by creating new session. You can achieve that either by opening new incognito window, or by opening new browser.

We hope that this is functionality that SDL will address in some future releases.

Answer (score 5):

While it's true that the product doesn't have a logout button, there is an Alchemy plugin available for that: [Logout plugin](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Logout).

Install it, make sure your browser prompts you for the username and password, and you can easily switch between test users from within the UI.